# Could Donald Trump flee to Russia?

Tags: united-states, president, donald-trump

Could Trump flee to Russia if evidence for collusion is exposed ?

What would happen then, could we arrest him or not ?

Comment: An elected official joining a foreign state might be called defecting. Extraditing him from Russia without their consent would be called world war three.

Comment: Given the premise, it might work out a little like the the plot of an [O. Henry story](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Ransom_of_Red_Chief).

Answer (score 4):

Well, if he could make it to Russia, and if Russia is offering him asylum (IMO, quite likely), no one can stop him from doing so.

The US could arrest him and put him on a wanted list if he does so (since this is likely to constitute treason), but the US can't really do anything about him. There is no treaty of extradition between the US and Russia, and even if there was one there would likely be an article which prevent political criminals (e.g. people charged with treason) from being extradited.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that Russia is already giving asylum to an US citizen who is considered a traitor by the US government: Edward Snowden.

Comment: @Philipp Snowden is not charged with treason, nor is he likely to be as a matter of law.